# Angular and msal.js, acquireTokenSilent adds extra browser history

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

We have an Angular 8 app using MSAL 1.2.1. Authentication is working correctly, and we're able to refresh the access token silently. We also are preventing the silent iframe load from loading our Angular app (both by the index.html detecting it's in an iframe, and the app itself doing the same)

The problem we're having is that after accquireTokenSilent refreshes the token, there are **two** new browser history items added, even though the Angular router hasn't routed to a different page. Using the browser Back button, or location.back(), hits these history items first, requiring **three** back requests to actually back up to the previous page.

I've seen examples of tracking the router NavigationEnd event to keep track of the previous page and/or a stack of the routings, and using router.navigate() to do the same thing. However, this **adds** to the navigation history rather than popping off the last item, and the Back button still has problems.

Anyone know if there's a way to prevent acquireTokenSilent from adding items to the browser history?

Comment: FYI - this was in Chrome 79.0.3945.130. An issue has been reported on the MSAL Github project with the same behavior in Safari. https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1310

Comment: FYI - MSAL 1.3.1 published 2020-05-13 fixes the issue.